# Crossplatform Offline Audio Processing Library

Tags: audio, signal-processing

I am looking for an audio dsp library for cleaning up some speech (voice) recording. I have not decided which language to use yet.

Here are the feature I am looking for:

- Work in Linux and Windows
- Importing MP3
- Working with multiple channels mixing
- Noise Filter
- Bandpass filter
- Compressor

I love to have these as well, but I can write my own if they are not available:

- De-esser
- multi-band compressor
- Expender
- Envelopes

---

(if you can suggest an application that do these in scripting / one mouse click, I will accept your answer too)

Comment: Just FYI, OpenAL don't work. Its effect are not tunable to do de-essing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like SoX?? http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Juce](http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php) from Raw Material Software.

It is free for non-commercial use, and very reasonably priced for commercial use.  it also has a lot of built in audio capabilities (mixing, file I/O, etc.) and has a nice cross platform GUI toolkit as well.

Comment: +1. It works, but not as self-contained as I hoped for. It requires VST plugins which are mostly windows-only

Comment: After some googling. I have found Ugen (http://code.google.com/p/ugen/), which extends Juce and do (most of) my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) does most of those things.

Comment: Audacity don't have the automation I needs. No scripting or things like that.

Comment: Actually, audacity if fully automAtable through what they call chains, sorry I can't provide links right now, typing from a mobile.

Comment: That's what I thought, although I have never used it. I thought there was some scripting ability that can automate tasks.

Comment: it is not "fully" automatable. just some simple export/import and filters.  It can't even split a channel.